# GUI Automation without display?

Tags: windows, display, gui

I have programs implemented with `AutoHotkey` or `Ranorex Studio` both working perfectly performing GUI Automation in Windows.

When deploying them on my another machine (board without display devices connnected) within LAN, it seems they only work under one of the following conditions:

1. run remotely after connected with remote desktop (with remote desktop session active)
2. run after connecting an external monitor to the board

Both are connected with a display adapter (1. remote display adapter / 2. local display adapter).

Is it possible that GUI Automation could be achieved without a display adapter?

PS: similar question: [Launch GUI application on Headless System](https://superuser.com/questions/1489124/launch-gui-application-on-headless-system)

Comment: If you really need a "display" - there's cheap (1-2 dollar) HDMI dummy adaptors. I think they're meant originally for the bitcoin mining market, but they work well for apps that need a 'real' monitor. I usually use it with remote desktop apps but it might work here.

Comment: See if this helps : [How to mock up a virtual display on a Windows 10 VM](https://superuser.com/questions/1511529/how-to-mock-up-a-virtual-display-on-a-windows-10-vm).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks a lot. I searched around HDMI dummy adaptors, the item description shows it helps solve the resolution-and-color-depth-not-configurable issue. Strangely I never encountered that when using Windows Remote Desktop.

Comment: Windows remote desktop dosen't care about having a display - I used it with parsec and nomachine since they need monitors.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah it adds a 'Microsoft Remote Display Adapter' upon connection which can be seen in the Device Manager.